# Decrypt binary string with CryptoJS and write to file

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past day, I'm trying to decrypt a binary string and then write it using CryptoJS. I got it working but the thing that gives me a headache is it's performance. I'm using some dirty workarounds to do it at the moment, but I'm pretty sure there is a faster and more efficient way.

```
convertWordArrayToUint8Array(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(base64ArrayBuffer(res), key))

//"key" is a 32 character string (passphrase)
//"res" is a binary string converted to an ArrayBuffer
```

Is my current attempt where I get the binary string as an ArrayBuffer with XMLHttpRequest, then convert it to a Base64 string and then decrypt it using CryptoJS. After decryption I convert the result to a Uint8 Array and write it into a file. It works, but it is pretty slow. Decrypting a 1 MB chunk in Chrome takes about 200ms and 100ms in Firefox.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *...then convert it to a Base64 string and then decrypt it...* Convert it **to** a base64 string? That can't possibly be correct.  *...It works,...* How do you know it works? It shouldn't.

Comment: I know that it works because I obviously tested it? And yes I know that this is not right, but it's my first time trying out CryptoJS. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity - why `CryptoJS`  I don't know much about it, but a lot of cryptographic functions you may need are readily available in the browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt

If it's possible to use the native API, I am guessing it's going to be a fair bit faster than a JavaScript implementation.

Comment: I was aware of the WebCryptoAPI but never tried it until now, and it's is waaaaaaaaaay faster than CryptoJS. I guess I need to rewrite some code but it will be worth.

Comment: Happy to hear it!